# Access denied for spFarm Account writing in sites root directory

Tags: 2013, development, file-upload

I was writing a custom solution for generating a sitemap programmatically.
This solution is running as the Farm Account in the timer service.

I don't know why I am always getting an Access Denied Error in the Testsystem everytime the job wants to save a file to the sitemaps root.

Here is the code I used to write the file to the root directory:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(new SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite securesite = new SPSite(site.ID))
    {
        securesite.RootWeb.Files.Add(filename, smWebMS.ToArray(), true);
    }
}));
```

whereas `filename = "sitemap.xml"` and the `MemoryStream smWebMS = filled with data`

What I don't understand is that I get an access denied even when I run it as FarmAccount and with elevatedPriviliges. I also granted Full Access to the Farm Account on WebApplication Level and Site Level.
[image: WebApplication Permissions]
[image: site permissions of farm account]
does annyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Error of ULS Log:

```
The Execute method of job definition Internet.Sitemap1.SitemapTimerJob (ID 5f05a087-4208-4e4d-b47b-801fec1336d4) threw an exception. More information is included below.  Error writeing file to rootweb: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: <nativehr>0x80070005</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>Access denied.    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object punkFile, Int64 cbFile, Object punkSPFileMgr, Object punkFFM, Int64 PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties, String bstrCheckinComment, String bstrLockIdMatch, String bstEtagToMatch, Int32 lockType, String lockId, Int32 minutes, Int32 fRefreshLock, Int32 bValidateReqFields, Guid gNewDocId, SPFileSaveParams sfsp, SPFileInfo& pFileProps, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage, String& pEtagReturn, Byte& piLevel, Int32& pbIgnoredReqProps)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.AddStreamOrBytesInternal(String urlOfFile, Stream file, Int64 fileSizeToSave, SPFileStreamManager spmgr, PutFileOpt fileOpt, String createdBy, String modifiedBy, Int32 createdByID, Int32 modifiedByID, DateTime timeCreated, DateTime timeLastModified, Object varProperties, String checkInComment, Stream formatMetadata, String lockIdMatch, String etagToMatch, SPLockType lockType, String lockId, TimeSpan lockTimeout, Boolean validateRequiredFields, SPVirusCheckStatus& virusCheckStatus, String& virusCheckMessage, String& etagNew, Boolean& ignoredRequiredProps)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.Add(String urlOfFile, Byte[] file, Boolean overwrite, String checkInComment, Boolean checkRequiredFields)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.Add(String urlOfFile, Byte[] file, Boolean overwrite)    
 at Internet.Sitemap1.SitemapTimerJob.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Execute>b__0()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)    
 at Internet.Sitemap1.SitemapTimerJob.Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Elevated privilages have no sence IMHO in this situation as your job runs already with farm account permissions.

Are you sure, that the Security Token Service (STS) is [up and running](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh564135.aspx)? In the past I had [similar security issues](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2016/04/18/cannot-find-an-spsite-object-error-from-powershell/) due to this service was stopped accidentally.

Comment: sadly this did not help :(
i restarted the STS on all Servers in the Farm but the Error still occures. Nevertheless i also don't have the same error as you. There are no hints about the Security Token Services in the ULS Logs. But it was worth a try and I thank you for your answer. 
The very strange thing is that in our development Farm (Single Server) there are no errors but in the Test-Enviroment (2 frontend -2 backend) there is this strange Access denied error. (btw. with the evelated privileges i tried to eliminate all sources for errors - with out success as far)